# How can I search in Selected Treeview?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have `find_all` button which helps to find the word everywhere. I implement it like this:

```
text = self.find_text.text()    
for i in range(self.model.columnCount()):
    results = self.model.findItems(text,QtCore.Qt.MatchContains | QtCore.Qt.MatchRecursive  | QtCore.Qt.MatchCaseSensitive ,i)
    for i in results:
         i.setData(QtGui.QColor(255,0,0), QtCore.Qt.ForegroundRole)
```

When I click the button I am getting this output as I expected.
[image: The result of find_all clicked]

Now I don't want to search everywhere. I just want to select "test4" or "test1" group and search just inside this group. All data created with "QStandardItem" .

```
self.model = GroupModel(self,self.headers)
self.tree_view = GroupView(self.model)
```

I am trying to do something like this:

```
selection = self.tree_view.selectedIndexes()[0]
all_children = selection.allChild #Something here I couldn't figure out.
```

`all_children` will be the list of selected tree

After that I can search in `find_all` function like this:

```
text = self.find_text.text()    
for i in range(self.model.columnCount()):
    results = self.model.findItems(text,QtCore.Qt.MatchContains | QtCore.Qt.MatchRecursive  | QtCore.Qt.MatchCaseSensitive ,i)
    for i in results:
         if i in all_children:
             i.setData(QtGui.QColor(255,0,0), QtCore.Qt.ForegroundRole)
```

I couldn't figure out how to get the list of treeview when I select the header of group. Can you please help me or give a suggestion?

Comment: `selectedIndexes()` returns all selected indexes, usually in order of selection, so, first of all you should ensure that you're choosing parent items. That said, you're already using the `MatchRecursively` flag, so you're probably using the wrong index.

Comment: I just want to get selected item's all child standart items.